# Minecraft crashing on startup [MAC]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've been having this issue with Minecraft. Every time I try to launch it, the game sends me this error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/minecraft/client/main/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

I noticed the "unsupported" message in the first line and tried updating my system as well as installing the new Minecraft launcher. The new launcher just doesn't start up at all, so there's no way for me to start Minecraft.

If anyone needs to know, I am running Mac OS X 10.8.

Thanks a lot to anyone who can help me with this!

Comment: Dumb question, but do you have the Mac version of minecraft?

Comment: @Ben, yes. Mac OS X 10.8; second last line.

Comment: @Zissouu thanks for the suggestion! I checked and I was using the latest version (Java SE 8 update 144) while having this problem. I just downgraded to SE8 update 79 and I'm still having the same problem. Thanks a lot for the suggestion though!

Comment: Update: I have just updated my system to Mac OS X 10.8.5 and am still having the same issue. Just wanted to clear that up in case of any "system update" answers. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

I've just done a little bit of testing and have eventually found a way for it to work.

- Double click on the app and select "Show package contents"
- Go into Contents > Resources > Java
- Start up Bootstrap.jar. It works as the Minecraft Launcher

Thanks to everyone who helped with this!